# Ejecutar .bat desde programador de Tareas como administrador

Tags: windows

tengo un .bat que se levantar el servicio de SQL SERVER, he creado un acceso directo y lo configure para que se ejecute como administrador, s ejecuto directamente dicho acceso directo el servicio se levanta correctamente, pero ahora necesito que ese .bat se ejecute en una tarea programada.

AL crear la tarea programada, direcciono para que ejecute el acceso directo, pero no logra levantar el servicio, no se pueda ser, la primera idea que tengo es que me faltaria indicarle a la tarea programada que se ejecute como administrador pero no se donde se configura eso.

Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas la tarea en la opciones de seguridad defines que se ejecute con los privilegios mas altos y cambia el usuario al usuario que precisas (también puede ser SYSTEM) y en acciones tu script.
[image: Ejecutar como Administrador]

Comment: gracias @oegpyg con eso quedo solucionado

Comment: muy buen aporte, gracias. A mi me funciono pero no creándolo directamente como administrador, lo cree con usuario normal y luego lo edite y lo deje como administrador.